# Доступ к локальному сайту из домашней сети

Tags: сеть, tomcat, маршрутизация

Есть много машин(офис). Все подключены через `wifi` к роутеру. Запускаю на одной машине сайт - `Tomcat8`, который доступен по адресу `localhost:8080`. Как мне сделать так что бы другие машины могли достучатся до этого сайта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас не стоит никаких ограничений на маршрутизаторе, то вам надо узнать ip адрес машины на которой запущен ваш сервер. И на других машинах использовать

```
<ip адрес сервера>:8080
```

Если у вас настроен внутренний сервер имен, то можно вместо ip адреса использовать внутреннее доменное имя сервера.